# Why would Linux Docker fail downloading files from private gcr.io?

Tags: permissions, docker, google-cloud

#### Issue

So... I have tested many different commands and it all works great except

```
docker pull gcr.io/...
```

which always says I don't have enough permissions:

> *ERROR: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication*

Why would that be?

I'm 100% sure I'm properly logged into Google Cloud since I can run commands such as `kubectl ...` that require that very same authorization.

#### My Environment

##### Host

I am running Linux Ubuntu (at this time 22.04) on amd64.

##### Guest

On that box, I need to run a VM for various reasons. So I have another Ubuntu 22.04 install which runs in a VirtualBox VM. Everything, as mentioned above, works just fine.

##### Docker

At this time, docker is installed as a `snap`, version 20.

***Note:** I could not use the default apt-get packages because these are not being updated and thus it is very old.*

The failing command is something like:

```
docker pull gcr.io/<path>/<to>/<file>:main-123456
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues at play here:

#### Snap Docker

The version of `docker` in `snap` is protected by `apparmor`.

The authentication fails because there is a need to read a file (maybe multiple?) from a sub-directory that starts with a period (such as `.docker/...`, although that one is authorized in `apparmor`).

As mentioned in the question, the old version is not going to cut it. So we are left with the new **Docker Desktop** version instead.

#### Docker Desktop

*(see notes below about installation & starting & usage)*

The Docker Desktop is a new beast. It has more security features, which is great, to some extend, but it's annoying since it means more resources being used. Specifically, it uses your computer VM capability to run docker. That's a great way to segregate an environment that can run as root.

**This is where you have another problem!** If you are already running in a VM, then chances are the Guest cannot itself create a *nested* VM. That's what will fail unless you make sure to authorize the VM to create nested VMs. There is an option just for that in VirtualBox which you can tweak from within the interface.

Here is a screen grab that shows you the default (i.e. not authorized!) Make sure that **Enabled Nester VT-x/AMD-V** flag is checked. If not checked, you'll have to shutdown your VM, check that box, then restart the VM.

[image]

---

##### Extra Notes

###### Remove Snap

First you'll want to remove the snap. This is done using the following:

```
snap remove docker
```

**WARNING:** Docker is going to make a full backup of your existing containers & images, in case you wanted to restore them when you re-install docker. This can take forever since most containers are really large files. I suggest you take the time to delete these first:

```
$ docker ps -a
$ docker rm <container-id>
$ ...repeat until `docker ps -a` returns an empty list...
$ docker images
$ docker rmi <image-id>
$ ...repeat until `docker images` returns an empty list...
```

**Note:** you may have to use `--force` to remove some of the images. Since we're getting rid  of everything, it's obviously *safe*.

###### Install Desktop Docker

I'll assume you are able to install this version on your own. Instructions for Ubuntu can be found here:

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/#install-docker-desktop

***Note:** Contrary to a normal PPA, their PPA does not allow you to directly install the `.deb`. Instead, you'll have to "manually" download a .deb and install it. It will then gather all the necessary dependencies, etc. Strange, if you ask me.*

###### Enable/Start

Once installed, you can start it. In my case, I used the following:

```
$ systemctl --user enable docker-desktop
$ systemctl --user start docker-desktop
```

It did not work the first time, try a few more times...

###### User Docker

Once the desktop window is open and not saying "Starting Docker" with a spinning wheel, the Docker is up and running and you can then type commands in your shell:

```
docker pull gcr.io/<path>
```

And that is expected to work like a charm.

*Side Note: The `docker-compose` command is now `docker compose` (no dash), so a sub-command of docker instead of a separate tool.*